# Se puede validar o restringir que a la hora de pegar caracteres dentro de input solo debe aceptar letras?

Tags: javascript, html, validación, eventos, input

Se podría validar que a la hora de pegar caracteres dentro de input solo debe aceptar letras o números
Hay algun evento que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que coloques ningún control de eventos en Js o algo por el estilo. Basta con que especifiques el tipo de input

```
<input type="number" min="2" max="20">
```

Agregando min y max especificas los valores máximos. No la cantidad de caracteres, sino los valores, es decir, irán del 2 al 20 en este caso.

En el caso de los textos

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5">
```

Permitiendo solo así que puedas poner 5 caracteres. Admite numero y letras.
(Cuidado si tomas valores numericos desde aquí, tengo entendido que lo tomará como un *string* y no como un *number*)

Podés leer más aqui: [Inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
```

El pattern es para los caracteres que acepta (solo letras en este caso) y el numero despues en llaves es para la cantidad maxima de caracteres.